# How to connect the text in each row of Excel to one sentence?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I would like to connect the text in each line of Excel to one sentence.

example

| Column A |
| --- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 |

->>>> "text1, text2, text3 ~"

I would appreciate it if you could let me know the Python code.

used pandas, but I don't know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you switching from Python to Excel and want to concatenate several cells within Excel? If so, you do not need Python. There are a few native methods for it.

Suppose you have `text1` in cell `A1`, `text2` in cell `A2` and `text3` in cell `A3`.

Method 1 :

`=A1&A2&A3`

Method 2 :

`=CONCAT(A1:A3)`

or

`=CONCAT(A1,A2,A3)`

Method 3:

`=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A3)`

All will return a text string `"text1text2text3"`.

If you also want commas in between, there are three ways to do it:

`=A1&","&A2&","&A3`

`=CONCAT(A1,",",A2,",",A3)`

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A3)`

All three will return a text string `"text1,text2,text3"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Data is inside a Pandas DF you can iterate over the column and append everything to a comma-seperated string:
Creation of df:

```
import pandas as pd
technologies = [
        ("Cell A"),
        ("Cell B"),
        ("Cell C")
        ]
 df = pd.DataFrame(technologies,columns= ['Column A'])
```

Iteration over Column A:

```
 String= ""
 for x in df['Column A']:
 String = String + x + " "
```

Output:

```
'Cell A Cell B Cell C '
```